# xamarin - Why the first "refresh" in my tabbed page doesn't work, but the next ones are good?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am a student working for a dev company, and i have to make an app to organize different book collections.
So, i had to make my "lists" into tabbed page, and cuz i don't know how many of them the user want to display, i have to add them dynamically, and control them with a specific tabbed page.
Everything work "fine", but, when i want to add a tab, the first time it doesn't work, then i try again, and it work fine (the previous one is taken into account this time), and the app start to work fine. Seem like it need time to "warm up", i don't know. I don't really understand why it only work after the 1st "refresh", so if someone had the same issue or have an idea, i will be grateful.
Thanks for reading me.

Code :
tabbedlist is the page that create the tab and the tabpage
addtabmenu is the page that add or remove which type i want to have on tab from a list

https://gfycat.com/tidywelldocumentedarcticduck

Comment: there is a Refresh(); in second constructor but not in first why? and what does Refresh(); do

Comment: I didn't know how to make a proper refresh, so i made a function who navigate to a new page.
There is only one refresh in the second because i need to refresh only if i add a new tab, and it's called when i add select from my list what i want to add as a tab in addtabpage.

Comment: you mentioned in your question **after the 1st "refresh"** did you meant by it the refresh() function?

Comment: Yes. 
-I open my app
-go to tabbedlistpage
-go to the page addtab (who is a permanent tab)
-chose a type on my picker
-it must add a tab, and call a new tabbedlistpage + refresh
-nothing appen
-try again, the exat same thing
-It work well, taking into account the previous changes

//I will try to mage a gif

Comment: TabbedListPage tab = new TabbedListPage();                                           
tab.CurrentPage = tab.Children[tab.Children.Count() - 1];
 this line of code is unclear since the tab.Children.Count()  will be be 0

Comment: Oh ok, thx.
I was testing things, is not what make my app act like that.

Comment: so you figured the problem?

Comment: Still not. I continue to search.

Comment: can you please replace the code in the refresh to this: TabbedListPage tab = new TabbedListPage();
            tab.CurrentPage = this.Children[0];
           
            Navigation.PushAsync(tab);

Comment: Not working, still the same problem you can see on the gif.

Comment: you can add a tab without navigation to fresh the view. i will write the code as an answer to help you then delete it.

Comment: one more thing please. replace your refresh function by this. TabbedListPage tab = new TabbedListPage(); tab.Children = this.Children; Navigation.PushAsync(tab);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a tab page. when the button in clicked it creates a new tab.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" >
         <Button HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
</TabbedPage>
```

code behind

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new EmailDetails()); // EmailDetails is the page you want to add to the tab
            navigationPage.Title = "email";
            this.Children.Add(navigationPage);
        }
```

Comment: Ok i see. Thanks.
I have to go now, but i come back in about 1.30 hour, i will try your answer and check this as accepted answer of it work.

Comment: I think i can manage to do something with your answer, thank you.